# What exactly occurs when selecting windows "Install Updates and shut down" logoff option?

Tags: windows, shutdown

When updates are available and the user selects Shut Down from the Windows start menu, a dialog appears with a menu for Shutdown, Log Off etc.

One option which appears is

"Install Updates And Shut Down"

The question is, what exactly happens when the user presses OK?

Is the task showing the dialog Explorer? (It seems impossible to tell with process monitor spying, because the desktop is frozen)

I assume (But am not sure) this is Explorer and when the user presses OK it calls ExitWindowsEx

If So the question is what is different when the user selects "Install Updates And Shut Down" would it send special flags to ExitWindowsEx or perhaps call another API and would there be any way to spy this functionality?

Comment: Why? Its a programming question about win processes and API

Comment: The *purpose* of your question isn't quite clear. Do you want to implement something similar? Understand better how windows works? Tweak the mechanism to do something different? Add your own action to the shutdown dialog?

Answer (score 0):

when the user clicks "ok", it logs out every connected user then it installs all pending updates. the update installation process does not execute in explorer. i think it executes under WinLogon, maybe through a [Winlogon notification package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380545%28VS.85%29.aspx). i don't know which system call would trigger this behaviour automatically...

however, you can have a look at the [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28VS.85%29.aspx) which should allow you to control automatic updates programmatically.

Comment: I have attached WinDbg to Explorer.exe with bp user32!ExitWindowsEx and can see the arguments passed in the cx and dx registers. I have tested from the start menu with a standard shutdown and also with an 'Install Updates And Shutdown' and in each case the arguments passed  is 9 for the flags (Shutdown + Poweroff) there seems to be no difference whatsoever in the ExitWindowsEx call. Disassembling Explorer.exe (With IDA PRO) shows it has an import of ExitWindowsEx but no cross-references. I would like to discover where the call is and what code surrounds it (in a dll perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

Im just throwing out some thoughts..

Maybe it puts an entry in this registry key before restarting: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Also check out the value ShutdownFlags in the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon